# How to fetch files from Azure Blob with current date in the path in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, mosaic-decisions

I am using **Mosaic Decisions** for a specific data pipeline I have to run on a **daily basis**. I have a client whose file location changes everyday in the **blob container** based on the **current date**.

For example, the file **sales.xlsx** has a path like
`daily_records/<current-date>/sales.xlsx`, where the  is a date value in format `yyyy-MM-dd.`

[image: Azure Reader Node]

I have tried to use the **System Parameter** `$(currentTime)`. However, this parameter also has a **timestamp** associated with it which doesn't satisfy my use case.

I would like to automatically get the **current date** when I run the mosaic flow and not have to re-type the date in the **path** everyday. How can I achieve this in **Mosaic Decisions**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar situation before, and the workaround for this is to use **calculated parameters** rather than **system parameters**.

First, Create a **calculated parameter** from the flow config menu with **Data Type** as **Date**. Give it a **Parameter Name** of **folderName**. Set the **Expression value** as `TO_DATE(TODAY('Asia/Calcutta'))`. Here, pass in your current **Timezone** in place of `'Asia/Calcutta'` if your current time zone is different from mine. Refer Screenshot below

[image: Create Calculated Parameter]

Then, in the **Reader Node** configuration menu, add your file path as `daily_records/$(folderName)/sales.xlsx`. The **path** would be updated daily with the new date and you can click on **validate** directly to get the **latest file** without having to type the new date every day.

[image: Path]